# MDX - Average for a Cube

Tags: mdx

I am trying to find the average value(val) for every month(1,2,3,4,...10) for a,b,c on the given cube below.

Here is my query:

```
select 
  ([Measures].[VAL1],[DIMPROPERTY TIME].[TIMEDIM].[MONTH])  on 0,
{[DIMPROPERTYLENDER].[Hierarchy].[NAME]} on 1

from [PropertyData2016]
```

I am pretty new to this, so any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: What does a,b,c represent?  The lender?

Comment: Have you resolved this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the msdn documentation and looked at the examples?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146067.aspx

Edit: Try this.

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.[AVGSALE] AS 
AVG ( 
    DESCENDANTS(
          [DIMPROPERTYLENDER].[Hierarchy].[NAME],
          [DIMPROPERTY TIME].[TIMEDIM].[MONTH].ALLMEMBERS)        
          ), 
          [Measures].[VAL1]
    )

SELECT NON EMPTY Measures.[AVGSALE] ON 0, 
    NON EMPTY ([DIMPROPERTYLENDER].[Hierarchy].[NAME], [DIMPROPERTY TIME].[TIMEDIM].[MONTH]) ON 1

from [PropertyData2016]
```

PS: you might need to use [DIMPROPERTY TIME].[TIMEDIM].[MONTH].**[MONTH]** in your final select.